# Confusion with serving static files with Django and fcgi

Tags: django, apache, fastcgi, shared-hosting

I thought I had this figured out, but I've read a few different things regarding this and I'm starting to get really confused.

The URL settings in my settings.py look like this:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = HOME + '/uploads'

MEDIA_URL = PUBLIC_HTML + 'media/'

STATIC_ROOT = HOME + '/static'

STATIC_URL = PUBLIC_HTML + 'static/'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = PUBLIC_HTML + 'static/admin/'
```

Where `HOME` is /home/username/ and `PUBLIC_HTML` is like "http://www.mydomain.com/test/myproject/"

I seem to be getting my static files okay, but my media files don't show up. I don't have anything set up in my urls.py file, and I'm using shared hosting, so all I can do is use the .htaccess file for apache directives.

Obviously, I'd like to get my media files to show up, but my first question is why are the static files showing up? It doesn't make sense. I thought that apache had to intercept these requests before they were processed by Django, but they seem to be showing up fine without any kind of django.static.serve business in the urls. How is that possible? Am I doing this right (I'm sure I'm not), and how do I get the media files to show up? Why aren't they showing up when the static files aren't?

Answer (score 0):

STATIC_ROOT must be served be apache on STATIC_URL, which you've done right apparently.

In the same fashion, MEDIA_ROOT must be served by apache on MEDIA_URL.

You could set up an [alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias), from MEDIA_URL to MEDIA_ROOT for example:

```
Alias /test/myproject/media/ /home/username/media/
```

It is preferable to avoid hard coding absolute paths, but first make sure that it works like this.

Comment: Can I put this Alias directive in the .htaccess file? I didn't do that for the `STATIC_URL/ROOT`.

Comment: Yes, [you can](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html). Also, did you check the logs ? I don't know what you did or didn't do: you did not post your apache configuration :)

Comment: I didn't post it because I don't have access to it, unfortunately. (Shared hosting). I don't appear to have access to the log either.